# 主観的という表現について

Tags: 討議, サポート, クローズ理由

主観的というのがどうも抽象的すぎて何を言っているのかピンときません。

質問と相談、程度の違いという認識で間違いないですか？

Comment: その表現が使われていた文脈が示されていませんが、「主観的な答えしか集まらない」というクローズ理由にはどのような質問が該当するのか、あるいは説明がわかりにくい、という話でしょうか。

Comment: @unarist 説明がわかりにくいということです。

Comment: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485/
かなぁ。

Comment: 確認なのですが、[@774RR さんのコメントの記事](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485/)で「いい『主観的』」とされている物もStackOverflow(日本語版)ではクローズ対象という事ですよね？

Comment: @mjy 主観的というのがどうも抽象的すぎて何を言っているのかピンときません。=主観的意味不明なんだけど他の言葉に置き換えてわかりやすく説明できる？(趣旨)＝@unarist 説明がわかりにくいということです。≠クローズの可能性の議論∴該当する質問はない

Comment: @mjy 何を言っているのかピンときません。（婉曲法）=わかりません（私が何を伝えたいか何を伝えているか理解いただけますか？、それともそれ以下のサイトに仕上げますか。私は、日本人だからといって面白い世界を隠すのはこれ以上耐えられません。）

Comment: [ピンとこない](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%81%A8%E6%9D%A5%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)もしこそのままの意味で言葉で置き換えたとしたらこの質問はどうなります。批判的な文に感じてしまいませんか？

Comment: 私が上のコメントで確認したかったのは、 http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485 で解説されている「いい主観」にしろ「よくない主観」にしろ、このサイトでは推奨されていないんですよね、という事です。そうならば、todoさんの質問とあまり関係ないかな、と思ったので。特に婉曲表現を使ったつもりはないです。

Comment: @mjy それだとそもそもの論点がずれています。主観的が意味不明だと言っている文です。意味不明な理由は抽象的だからだと述べたのです。そして最後に、具体性をもたせ直感的に理解できるようにしてほしいと書き記したのです。

Comment: ああ、今分かりました「（婉曲法）=わかりません」というのはtodoさんが婉曲表現を理解できない、という意味ではなくて、「ピンときません」が「わかりません」の婉曲表現だ、という意味なんですね。ちょっと難しいです。

Comment: 不安になって「ピンときません」で調べました。かなり昔から使っていた表現だったのですが、知恵袋で２００７年の質問で初めて登場していて回答者もそれぞれの回答を書いていたのでかなり不安でしたが一応、辞書にあって、置き換えたらかなりきつい批判文に思えたのでそのままにしてあります。翻訳システムと同じで短い文ほど曖昧性があり多様に捉えることができるために正しく伝わらないと自然言語処理の本で最近、知りました。幼少の時から正しく伝えることに難しさを感じ改善中です。

Comment: いや、単語は大丈夫です。私も早とちりしました。

Answer (score 4):

「主観的」といっても、哲学を始めるわけではなく、サイト運営の都合上のポリシーですから、そんなに難しく考える必要は無いと思います。

- 回答者の意見が分かれ、議論が始まるような事がら
- 回答者が各々の好みを披露するだけに終始するような事がら

程度の理解でいいのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

[ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)より：

> 一部の主観的な質問は許されますが、「主観的」とは「何でもあり」という意味ではありません。すべての主観的な質問は建設的であることが期待されます。どういう意味でしょうか?建設的で主観的な質問とは以下のようなものです。
>
> - 「なぜ」と「どうやって」を説明する回答を引き出す
> - 短い回答ではなく長い回答がつきやすい
> - 建設的で公正、かつ偏らないトーンである
> - 意見よりも経験を共有することを歓迎する
> - 意見が事実と参考資料で裏付けされていると主張する
> - 単なる思慮のない交流を楽しむものではない

英語版の最初の頃によくあった主観的な質問は：

- [一番好きなプログラミング言語での嫌いな点とは？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282329/what-are-five-things-you-hate-about-your-favorite-language)
- [一番好きなプログラミング漫画とは？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon?rq=1)
- [コード10行以内にどの素晴らしいこと作れる？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811074/what-is-the-coolest-thing-you-can-do-in-10-lines-of-simple-code-help-me-inspir?lq=1)

この質問は一つ回答がありません。意見等を集めているだけなんで、Q&Aサイトでは認めないように決めました。基本的に、意見募集、意見交換、討議等が目的であれば、「主観的」になる可能性が高まります。

Comment: 私の理解←（主観的な質問＝相談）：？

Comment: 相談(noun consultation; discussion)＋overlap≒凝議(noun deliberation; consultation)