# 開発に当たっての意見を募るような質問はオフトピック？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方, 話題の範囲

難しい質問かと思いますが、ふと疑問に思ったので……。
回答が複数あり議論に発展しそうな質問は「主観的な質問」かと思いますが
よく見るのが、
「○○言語で開発を進めたいが、参考になるものはあるか？」
(参考文献、参考書籍について尋ねる質問)
これは、ありなのでしょうか？
(幾つか見受けられ且つプラス票も入っているようなので……)

他で質問としてありそうなものだと例えば
「○○の機能は現在では使われるべきか否か」や、
「○○を実現するために現在主流となっている機能は？」など
私的見解を含んだ主観的質問は質問していいものでしょうか？
(※現在問題になっているから質問しているわけではないです。
あくまで例として記載しているだけです。)

”主観的”というのが開発にどれほど関わればいいのか？とか
個人の意見が入り”主観的”とは言え「一般的にはこう考えられるている」ような質問はアリなのか？とか

線引きがうまくできません。
皆様の意見を聞かせていただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

どのような質問は避けるべきですか?
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

---

関連
[主観的という表現について](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2183)
[参考ブログ記事: いい「主観的」、よくない「主観的」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1485)

Comment: 「○○の機能は現在では使われるべきか否か」より、「○○の機能を現在使われているが、○○が不満です。○○の解決方法とは？」にしたらどうですか？何を使うべきかは環境・目的・制限等によって変わるので、主観的な意見より、現在の問題を説明したら適切な回答が得られると思います。

Comment: @jmac 例としてあげただけなので色々と齟齬はあるかもしれません。勿論、その時々で状況や質問の仕方も変わるかと思います。(サーバの構築の際のモジュール制限など環境についてや、アクセス量や呼び出される頻度など)、、、主題としては、`その分野の知識は一切ないもの`として回答いただけると助かります。(※要するに何が問題点になるかも不明な場合です)

Comment: よく読んでみたら認識に違いがありそうなので本文を修正しました。

Comment: 参考文献を尋ねる質問はリスト質問に近い気も: [分析: 「いいライブラリ / ツールはありませんか」系のQ&Aでもっと欲張るには](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1512/8000) [「Xの一覧が知りたい」という質問の傾向と他サイトでの対応](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1381/8000)

Comment: 論点が「質問を改善するには？」になっているのですが、
ドチラかというと知りたいのは「どこまで曖昧で、主観的で、多数の回答がある質問であれば、SOに受け入れられるのか？(オフトピックではないか？)」ですかね。
ハッキリ線引きできないとは理解しているので、例にこんな質問のパターンではどうか？と提起している次第になります。
例えば次の質問(#1661, #8441)は回答がついていますし、プラス票もあります。
受け入れられているように感じる一方で多岐に渡る回答が並んでいて有益な情報を読み取りづらくもあり、
SO的には、このような質問はどうなのか？と感じています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「主観的な質問」オフトピックの目的は、 Q&A ではなくディスカッションになってしまうとノイズが増えてしまうから、それは避けたいためにクローズさせる、だと思っています。さらに言うと、回答が発散してしまうのを防ぐため、とも言えるかもしれません。

逆に、そこまで発散しなさそうならば、画一的にルールを定めてそこからはずれたからクローズ、する必要はないのかもしれないとは思ってはいます。

---

それを踏まえて、それぞれの問題系統に対する個人の見解を。

## 1. 参考文献・参考書籍

すでに言及されているっぽいですが、基本的に買い物リスト質問に該当するので、どちらかというとオフトピックだと思います。

## 2. 現在主流系

現在主流かどうかどうかを聞くのは、オフトピックだと思います。回答が時間の経過に対して定まらず、次々回答が寄せられていくのはどうかと思うからです。 (なので「主観的な質問」オフトピックではなく、「回答が定まらない」オフトピックだと思っています。そんな用語があるかは若干微妙ですが。。)

ただ、ベストプラクティスは何か？系の質問は確かオッケーだったような記憶があります。 (若干記憶が怪しいですが)

記憶が正しいとすると、そのように質問した場合には、ベストプラクティスが確立されているような分野に対してはおそらく問題ないでしょう。そうでない分野で、実質主観的な回答しか集まらないような質問もあるかもしれません。 (パッとは具体例は出てきませんが・・・) その場合はオフトピックなのではないでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど、そうですね。情報は常に古くなっていくものですし、その時のものが未来でも正しい情報とは限らないですね。例えばなのですが、自分で調査した結果で機能のそれぞれのメリットデメリットを尋ねたりし、そうすることで実装の取捨選択を自身で行う分には大丈夫ですよね？

Comment: @Myaku 最終的な判断はコミュニティによってなされるので、自分がどうこういう話ではないかもしれないですが、回答が発散しないような形での質問であるならば、オフトピックになる可能性は低いと思っています。

Answer (score -1):

主観的な質問とは、**全く同じ前提で全く同じ内容を質問している**のに、**質問者によってベストアンサーが異なる**可能性のある質問を言います。

しかし、私は焦点の定まった質問と明確な回答を求めています。私が同じトラブルに遭遇した際に素早く確実に問題を解消できる方法です。これを検索しているとき、曖昧な質問と何をすべきかはっきりしない回答は障害でしかありません。

現在問題になっていない事を質問すべきではありません。**失敗しない方法を訊かないでください。失敗の解決策を訊いてください。** 問題に遭遇してから質問し（勿論同様の事例が無いかサイト内で検索するのが先です）、有効な解決策が提示・発見された場合はそれを指し示し皆と共有してください。

Comment: "参考文献"については既に問題になってますよね？、それに対して、将来的に起こりうる問題を提起し、パターン分けを行えば、他の方が質問する際の指標にもなりえます。事前に質問することが悪いこととは私は思いません。

Comment: いいえ。事前に質問するべきではありません。それはノイズになる可能性が高いです。それが私の線引きです。あなたが異なる境界をお持ちならご自分で回答を作成し、投票を仰いでください。

Comment: 事前に質問するのがいけないとなると、セキュリティ関連の質問などは全滅しそうです。困ります。

Comment: 事前に質問するのが良いのか？悪いのか？はこの質問とは関係ありませんので、必要であれば別の質問を立ててください。ここでその件に関して回答・議論するのは見当違いです。

Comment: @mjy 「主観的な質問をどの程度許容するか」に対する許容範囲の線引きです。事前の質問の全てを拒否していません

Comment: 新たな議題が出ることは無駄ではありませんし、有意義であると考えますが主題と関係のない回答・議論はすべきではないという意見です。今回出た議論は主題からそれるため、新たに質問を行い別の主題で議論すべきです。主題に対しての建設的な議論を望んでおりますので、議論を主題に戻す行為を相対的に比較し他者の意見を貶めるようなコメントはご遠慮願います。

Comment: @Myaku 私はあなたの質問に対し「主観的な質問であっても実際に遭遇している問題であれば容認し、実際に遭遇していないのなら許容しない」という自身の基準を回答しています。「皆様の意見を聞かせていただければ幸いです。」と尋ねておきながら、その回答の内容に反対意見をコメントしたのはあなたです。私は自身の基準を参考として回答したに過ぎません。意見を聞かせて欲しいと言った者が「わたしはそうは思わない」と突っ返す。これ以上無礼な対応がありますか？

Comment: @G.Yamada いいえ、議論するために設けた質問で反対意見を出すことが無礼とは思いません。それでは回答は全て議論せずYesマンのように同意しろと仰るのですか？それでは討議の意味がありませんよね？そもそもとして問題が発生していない案件に対し事前に質問することの是非については私は尋ねておりません。それを前提にコメントを見た場合、mjyさんのコメントから別の方面への議論へ発展しそうだったので別の質問を立てることで主題からそれることを回避しようと致しました。最初のコメントから行き成り別の質問へとは言っておりませんので悪しからず。改めて客観的に初めから流れを読み返してみてはいかがでしょうか？これ以上の問答も主題とは関係ありませんので、此方の返信で最後にさせていただきます。ご回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: 「主観的かつ事前的な質問」の話でしたね。誤読し議論をミスリードしたようです。申し訳ありません。確かに、主観的かつ事前的な質問は、良い質問になり難いでしょうね。

Comment: @Myaku コメントに反対意見を残せば議論の火蓋は切られます。私は議論するつもりはなくそれが不毛である事を知っていたので異なる意見があれば「回答として作成せよ」とアドバイスしました。「事‌​前に質問すること」を焦点にしたのもあなたです。愚かな質問者はノイズしか生みません。ご苦労様でした

Comment: なんか変に拗れあって平行線になってるけど、主観的な質問について回答してるのを主が回答を読み取れず理解していなくて(二人コメント見られるけどミスリードするということは回答の仕方にも問題がある)、お互い熱が入ってるから意固地になってんだよね。言い方もお互いに煽ってるし、他になんか言い方無かったのかとｗ、主は逸れる前から自治するより逸れてから誘導すればよかったし、討議なのに議論しないってのもどんだけ自分の意見を通したいのかと思っちゃうねｗ